# Keep checkboxes in array checked on form submit

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, mysqli

I have a list of `checkboxes` created by a `while loop` but when the form is submitted the `checkboxes` are cleared.  I have tried to use the `unique id` of the value in the record by putting it in a hidden field and then using it in an `if query` before marking the `checkbox` as checked but it does nothing

```
<?php 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $posted = $row['auditID'];
?>
 <tr class="hover">
    <td width="180"><? echo $row['auditName']; ?>
       <input type="hidden" name="audit_id_confirm" value="<? echo $row['auditID'];?>">
    </td>
    <td width="33"><input type="checkbox" name="audit_selected[]"
       value="<? echo $row['auditID'];?>" 
       <?php if($_POST['audit_id_confirm'] == $posted){ echo "checked"; }?>>
    </td>  
 </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sorted it by checking id=f the id number was in the arrays that had been posted.

```
<?php
    $selected = $_POST['audit_selected'];

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $audit = $row['auditID'];
        if(in_array($audit, $selected)) {
               $check="checked='checked'";
        }else{
           $check = '';
        } ?>
        <tr class="hover">
            <td width="180">
                <?php echo $row['auditName'].' '.$num_audited; ?></td><td width="33">    <input type="checkbox" name="audit_selected[]" value="<?php echo $row['auditID'];?>" <?php echo $check; ?> >
            </td>  
        </tr>
    <?php }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($_POST['audit_id_confirm'] == $posted){ echo "checked"; }?>>
```

Replace above line with this:

```
<?php if($_POST['audit_id_confirm'] == $posted){ echo "checked='checked'"; }?>>
```

You are not properly providing `checked` attribute to the Html entity.

Comment: what exactly you want to do

Comment: when the form is posted I want it to retain the checks in the checked boxes

Comment: I have checked and found the problem is `$_POST['audit_id_confirm']` is not posted that's why it is not appearing.paste your complete code

Comment: which bit of the code do you want, the page is about 900 lines long.  The value does post because I can echo the value further down in a page but I don't want to view that, I just want the checkboxes to stay checked

Comment: dump both  `$_POST['audit_id_confirm']` and `$posted` and see are they same or not ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the information you need to store in the table, is the state of the checkbox. 
So, you can create a new column in your table, call it "checkboxstate".
Now inside your code use the following code to insert the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo($posted); ?>">
```

Thus far we have created several checkboxes whom names are the same as $posted, in other words each checkbox will have the name of its row's "$posted" value.

Now the only thing that is left is submitting the form and storing the checkbox info, which will return either TRUE or FALSE, and we will save that in our table, in the "checkboxstate" column.

So now in our table we will have a bunch of rows with several columns, one of the columns will be "checkboxstate" whom value will be either TRUE or FALSE.

At this point we have pretty much solved the problem, all that is left is to insert a simple if to either show a checked checkbox or an unchecked one.

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$posted = $row['auditID'];
$cbs = $row['checkboxstate'];
?>
<tr class="hover">
<td width="180"><? echo $row['auditName']; ?></td>
<td width="33">
<?php if($cbs == "true") echo "<input type='checkbox' name='$posted' checked='checked'>"; else echo "<input type='checkbox' name='$posted'>"; 
</td>  
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but using the table wasn't really an option because I have several pages where I want to do something similar with different values etc